# Can't Upload 5MB - 10MB image file to Lambda through API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, base64, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, compression

I am trying to upload 5MB image to aws lambda through api gateway.
I need to pass the file content as binary or buffer without any conversion. But API gateway converts the input as base64

by default and the converted base64 text is 7MB. As **the data size is increased after base64 conversion** lambda is not allowing that size. 
**How to prevent this automatic base64 conversion in API Gateway?
In AWS forum most of them were suggested to upload the file to s3 bucket and use that in lambda. But in my case i need to pass it directly to lambda without the help of S3. I have been at this for some weeks now....any help or insight is appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

[As documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), the maximum payload size for synchronous invocation (as from API Gateway) is 6 MB.

That means that, if you have larger payloads, you will need to break them up into multiple requests and combine those requests for processing. Which means that you need some form of storage to hold the pieces, and a way to link the pieces together.

If you need to upload a larger payload in a single request, and can't use an alternative such as uploading to S3 first, then Lambda isn't for you.